# SDN: DataIntegrityViolationException when persist entity / unique index with REST api

Tags: neo4j

I'm using SDN 3 with rest api and neo4j 2 server

I have an empty database and I'm trying to save new entity. spring-data fail to save entity when I have unique constraint on my index

this is my classes:

```
@NodeEntity
public class User extends AbstractEntity{

@Indexed(unique = true) String userName;
public String getUserName() {
return userName;
}

public void setUserName(String userName) {
this.userName = userName;
}
}

public abstract class AbstractEntity {

    @GraphId
    private Long id;

    public Long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {

        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }

        if (id == null || obj == null || !getClass().equals(obj.getClass())) {
            return false;
        }
        return id.equals(((AbstractEntity) obj).id);

    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        return id == null ? 0 : id.hashCode();
    }

}


public interface UserRepository extends GraphRepository<User> {

    User findByUserName(String userName);

}
```

this is the stacktrace:

```
Grave: Servlet.service() for servlet [cooper] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Unique property class java.lang.String userName rel: false idx: true was to be set to duplicate value user1] with root cause
org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: Unique property class java.lang.String userName rel: false idx: true was to be set to duplicate value user1
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.IndexingPropertyFieldAccessorListenerFactory$IndexingPropertyFieldAccessorListener.addUniquely(IndexingPropertyFieldAccessorListenerFactory.java:94)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.IndexingPropertyFieldAccessorListenerFactory$IndexingPropertyFieldAccessorListener.valueChanged(IndexingPropertyFieldAccessorListenerFactory.java:84)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.notifyListeners(DefaultEntityState.java:137)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.fieldaccess.DefaultEntityState.setValue(DefaultEntityState.java:114)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.setEntityStateValue(SourceStateTransmitter.java:70)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.access$100(SourceStateTransmitter.java:40)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(SourceStateTransmitter.java:105)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter$3.doWithPersistentProperty(SourceStateTransmitter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.mapping.model.BasicPersistentEntity.doWithProperties(BasicPersistentEntity.java:261)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.SourceStateTransmitter.copyPropertiesTo(SourceStateTransmitter.java:102)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.write(Neo4jEntityConverterImpl.java:167)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister$CachedConverter.write(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:179)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:243)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.mapping.Neo4jEntityPersister.persist(Neo4jEntityPersister.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:308)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.support.Neo4jTemplate.save(Neo4jTemplate.java:302)
    at org.springframework.data.neo4j.repository.AbstractGraphRepository.save(AbstractGraphRepository.java:115)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.executeMethodOn(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:358)
    at org.springframework.data.repository.core.support.RepositoryFactorySupport$QueryExecutorMethodInterceptor.invoke(RepositoryFactorySupport.java:343)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor$1.proceedWithInvocation(TransactionInterceptor.java:96)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:260)
    at org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:94)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.invoke(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:155)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:172)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:204)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy47.save(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:317)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:198)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy48.save(Unknown Source)
    at com.srs.portail.cooper.core.identity.services.IdentityServiceImpl.addUser(IdentityServiceImpl.java:29)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
```

Same exception occurs when using SDN 2 and neo4j 1.8, and disappears when using embedded database or removing unique constraint

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the same behavior. Looks like you actually end up with 2 new node entries on save. The node you you intend to save, and an additional node with just the indexed property.

neo4j-sh (?)$ START a = node(*) RETURN a;

==> | Node[16]{**type**:"...Person",name:"Bill Murray",id:1532} |

==> | Node[17]{id:"1532"}

Do you see the same thing?